# How to match up values in two columns from two different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

We have two different excel workbooks (WB1 and WB2) that have similar columns. One column labelled "UPC/EAN" and another column labelled "Inventory/Stock". What we are trying to do is match up the values in the "Inventory/Stock" column for a UPC in the "UPC/EAN" column on the same row on WB1 with the corresponding value in the "UPC/EAN" column in WB2 and have the value from WB1's "Inventory/Stock" column for that UPC entered in to the "Inventory/Stock" column of WB2. For example, if UPC "123456789" in the "UPC/EAN" column of WB1 has the value of "2" in the same row of column "Inventory"/"Stock" on WB1, that "2" would be placed in the "Inventory"/"Stock" column of WB2 on the same row as UPC "12345679" in column "UPC/EAN". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Index/Match functions will be more efficient then VLookup.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the vlookup function. It is meant to do exactly what you are looking for. If you run into an issue - simply look-up the help on vlookup function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

1. The UPC/EAN column is to the left of the stock column (In WB1)
2. The UPC/EAN column only contains unique values

Then the VLookUp function will work, see link https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

but basically...

Take the name of the workbook (eg *WB1*)

The name of the table in WB1 (eg *Table1*)

The Names of the columns from WB1 (eg *UPC/EAN* and *Inventory/Stock*)

The name of the UPC column in WB2 (eg *UPC/EAN2* -  it doesnt matter if its the same column name as in the 1st table, im just changing it for clarity)

Count how many rows to the right the stock column is from the UPC column and then add 1. eg if the stock column is the first column to the right of the UPC column (ie, next to it) then count 2

Finally, in the stock column in WB2, type the following:

=VLOOKUP([@**UPC/EAN2**],**WB1**!**Table1**[[**UPC/EAN**]:[**Inventory/Stock**]],**2**,FALSE)